# Disable links for a specific product category in Woocommerce shop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, permalinks, product

How can I disable link to woocommerce single product page for a specific category?

I mean want to disable the option of clicking to open single product page for a specific category not all categories. So, there's some categories I need it to work with single page as normal.

To clarify: I want in this category to show product photo and name and disable when try to click to open product page.

Answer (score 0):

For a defined product category *(or product categories)* the following code will:

- Remove the link on the product
- Remove the button under the product photo

in shop and archive pages.

You will have to define in both functions your targeted product category (or product categories):

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_shop_loop_items' );
function custom_shop_loop_items() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'custom_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );
}

// Removing the product link
function custom_template_loop_product_link_open() {
    global $product;

    // HERE define your product categories in the array (can be either IDs, slugs or names)
    $terms =  array( 't-shirts', 'hoods' ); // Coma separated

    $link = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_product_link', get_the_permalink(), $product );

    if( has_term( $terms, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) )
        echo '<a class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link">';
    else
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link">';
}

// Removing the product button
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'filter_loop_add_to_cart_link', 20, 3 );
function filter_loop_add_to_cart_link( $button, $product, $args = array() ) {

    // HERE define your product categories in the array (can be either IDs, slugs or names)
    $terms =  array( 't-shirts', 'hoods' ); // Coma separated

    if( has_term( $terms, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) )
        $button = '';

    return $button;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks Loic for your sharing, It works fine in Removing the product button.
But it's still have been clickable and open the product in single page.
How can I solve that.

Comment: @Mohamed Sorry but this code is for shop and archive pages… It remove completely any link and buttoon for the related products that are in the targeted product categories only. So I don't understand what is the problem. This is tested and works. If not is because your theme or a plugin have maid changes and in this  case I can't guess it.